# $A\in \mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is the matrix representing $f$. Show that if $\mathrm{Coker}(f)$ is finite, then $|\det A|=|\mathrm{Coker}(f)|$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, free-modules

Let $M$ be a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank $n$, and $f:M\to M$ be a homomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.

$A\in \mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is the matrix representing $f$ with respect to a fixed $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of $M$.

Show that if $\mathrm{Coker}(f):=M/\mathrm{Im}(f)$ is finite, then $|\det A|=|\mathrm{Coker}(f)|$, and for a prime $p$ with $p\nmid |\mathrm{Coker}(f)|$ the induced map $f':M/pM\to M/pM$ is an isomorphism of
 $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$-modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that by t[he structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain), you can make two separate base changes of $M$, so that with respect to the two new bases, the matrix of $f$ looks like
$$
D = \begin{bmatrix}
d_{1} \\
 & d_{2}\\
&& d_{3}\\
&&& \ddots\\
&&&&d_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for integers $d_{i} > 0$ (as the cokernel is finite, see just below).

Thus
$$
\operatorname{Coker}(f) 
\cong 
\mathbb{Z} / d_{1} \mathbb{Z} \oplus \dots \oplus \mathbb{Z} / d_{n} \mathbb{Z}
$$
has order 
$$
d_{1} \dots d_{n} = \det(D).
$$
Now if $S, T$ are the matrices of the two base changes, we will have
$$
S A T = D,
$$
so that 
$$
\det(D) = \pm \det(A),
$$
as $S, T$ are invertible integer matrices.